# Z-Wave Switch Worked and then didn't

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

It's possible that this question is too general to be asked here, but I'm pulling my hair out, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the subject.

I installed a Leviton Z-Wave switch in a 2-gang box, using a length of 14-gauge wire to connect into the three neutral wires in a wirenut in the box. The load wraps around the bottom red pole and daisy chains to the other switch. Seems weird, but that's how it was originally.

So I turn on the breaker, everything works fine. I'm a genius. Then, I turn the breaker off again, repack everything into the junction box, screw in the switch, and replace the switchplate.

Breaker on - light doesn't turn on anymore. All the other ones do, and I read current going through it with my voltmeter. So, I unpack everything, everything looks good, fiddle with some wires, turn it on again and nothing.

I put back the original switch and it works fine, so it's not the light. Is it possible I blew out the switch somehow? Is there something else I might be missing? I've replaced lots of switches, but this is the first time I've encountered a problem like this.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?  It sounds like you swapped line and load on the switch...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I reverted everything before I had a chance, but this is the original switch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aSsn.jpg. It's the one on the left - top wire was to Black, bottom to Red, then the other switch, and the neutral to white.

Comment: Can you post the instructions for the switch you used for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sure thing: http://www.leviton.com/en/docs/DI-000-DZS15-02A-W.PDF

Comment: I can tell you right now that that red-wire is likely an always-hot wire, can you check that for me?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I believe so. Getting pretty close to the edge of my knowledge, but volt meter reads 120 from bottom pole to ground in on or off position. Between the top and bottom poles, it reads 0 in the on position and 120 in the off position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Smart switches don't like being upside down and backwards

What happened with your smart switch is that you swapped the Line and Load terminals -- it would not surprise me if something is acting goofy, or if the switch is somehow damaged even, as a result of that.  Try connecting the red wire to the Line terminal on a new smart switch with a proper pigtail (instead of the current configuration) and the black wire to the Load terminal -- you wired up the neutral and ground fine, though.

If that doesn't do the trick, I'd make sure nothing is shorting when you stuff it into the backbox -- wrapping the device with electrical tape and ensuring screws are tight helps.

Comment: Yep, I think you're right. The bottom wire (the one that loops from the bottom pole to the other switch) is definitely the line. I had connected that one to the red pole instead of the black. Thanks for your help - I'll try it again in daylight and see if I haven't destroyed this thing.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I changed it up this morning, and everything is working just fine. Thanks again for your help, I feel a bit dumb now that I see the answer was so obvious.